# I need to control access to a Views-generated JSON feed with OAuth

Tags: views, 6, authentication-authorization

I'm looking for a way to control access to a Views-generated JSON feed via OAuth, so individual users from a partner site can authorize access to certain of their profile data for use by the partner.

At this point, it seems clear that I need to use the services module with its attendant OAuth authentication to create a server that can hand over JSON. Is there some way I can use views to drive a server?

Answer (score 0):

With the services and services_views modules, it's possible to repurpose any view into a service with OAuth authentication.

From my testbed, here's what the URL for the service looks like:

```
http://services.localhost:8082/sample_endpoint/views/tracker.json
```

where "sample_endpoint" is the name of the endpoint, "tracker" is the name of the view being provided as a service, and ".json" is the format for the returned content.

Comment: So what part of this URL is the Oauth: the port #? the 'services' sub-domain? How is authentication handled? Through a message header?